# Select tag not properly styled on stock Android Browser

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show two select boxes in a WebView in Android (4.2.1), but the height of them aren't the correct. In higher Android version (4.4.2) the result is correct with the same CSS. I'm using Bootstrap.

**HTML code:**

```
    <div class="row col-xs-12 texto-cent barrasearch2 separacion-filas visible-xs" id="barraInbox">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 ident-der">
           <select size="1" name="cmd2" class="select-mod">
               <option value="mg_move">Move messages to</option>
               <option value="mg_copy">Copy messages to</option>
               <option selected="" value="mb_change">Open mailbox</option>
           </select>
           ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.select-mod{
    height: 30px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    -webkit-appearance: menulist !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

**Result in Android 4.2.1:**

[image]

**Correct result: (with Bootstrap CSS classes)**
[image]

Thank you for advance!

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the important marks, as usually they mess with my CSS a bit. Try a more specific path to the CSS style:

```
   #barraInbox div select.select-mod {
       height: 30px;
       font-size: 14px;
       -webkit-appearance: menulist;
       background-color: #fff;
       line-height: 1.42857143;
   }
```

It's hard to tell without knowing what they should look like. There might be a better way to do it. Could you link an image of how it should look?

Comment: I put the image above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
  height:25px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  -webkit-appearance: listbox;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDQAEAIAAAAAAAP8A/yH5BAEHAAEALAAAAAANAAQAAAILhA+hG5jMDpxvhgIAOw==); /* a simple arrow img */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Please try this this will work for you.